# Is there a makefile option to delete the obj files only but leaving the targets intact?

Tags: linux, makefile

I am short of disk space while trying to compare different releases of Android (each of them takes about 6-7G after building).
I thought there is an option for make (similar to make clean) that it will delete all the intermediate .obj files and leaves the target(s) alone. But I couldn't remember what it is; or is there an option like that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A makefile will do whatever it's written to do. The `clean` target is a convention for makefiles, not a feature of Make. A makefile need not have a `clean` rule; if there is a `clean` rule, and if it is written well it will clean out the files you wanted cleaned out, if it is written badly there's no limit to how badly it can mess things up.

If you are writing (or editing) a makefile, you can put in a rule for removing object files. If you are using a makefile written by someone else, either it has such a rule or it doesn't.

Comment: I guess I had a mental block when I posted the question. Yes, it all depends on how the makefile itself is implemented. Now I remembered that the "clean-obj" target was implemented in a makefile I used years ago.

Comment: Of course the implementation of the makefile matters, but in more ways that apparent. As @Jacek Konieczny wrote but didn't explain, if the makefile is using implicit rules, then implicitly created files are deleted automatically - as is the case if you use a chain of implicit rules to go from say a .c file to an a.out file through some implicit .o file. But the moment you mention explicitly one of the implicit files, it will have to be deleted explicitly too, or added to .INTERMEDIATE for it to be automatically deleted. So maybe the functionality you remembered deleting object files was this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the .INTERMEDIATE directive will help. From the GNU Make documentation (10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules):

> The second difference is that if `make' _does_ create B in order to
>   update something else, it deletes B later on after it is no longer
>   needed.  Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before`
>   make' also does not exist after `make'.`make' reports the deletion
>   to you by printing a `rm -f' command showing which file it is
>   deleting.
>
> Ordinarily, a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the
>   makefile as a target or prerequisite.  However, you can explicitly
>   mark a file as intermediate by listing it as a prerequisite of the
>   special target `.INTERMEDIATE'.  This takes effect even if the file is
>   mentioned explicitly in some other way.